# Can I use Jupyter notebooks in vs code without installing anaconda?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

In almost every tutorial that I have seen, it is suggested to install anaconda in order to work with jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code, but I don't want all the packages that anaconda offers. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: No, jupyter is its own local host entity that runs on the anaconda platform. However, there is a separate VS Code API that seems pretty promising as a notebook. See: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/notebook

Comment: @LarrytheLlama there is no mention of Anaconda in that linked page.

Comment: @merv I misread the question - I thought that he didn't want anything to do with anaconda - my mistake

Comment: There are also minimal Conda installers such as Miniconda, Miniforge, or - my personal favorite - Mambaforge. Same deep support for compiled dependencies and minimal environments, without any of the default data science packages of Anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed the `Python` extension, it is bound with `Jupyter` and `Pylance` extensions.

[image]

And you can create the jupyter notebook with the command of `Jupyter: Create New Jupyter Notebook`:

[image]

And you can switch the kernels:

[image]

After you selected the python interpreter in the Jupyter Notebook, if this environment has not installed the related packages, it will prompt this:

[image]

You only need to click install, then the Jupyter extension will help you to install all the packages.

Comment: that looking to be working, curios to know how does this work. does this start jupyter server and kernel automatically

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Jupyter does not need to have anaconda installed. You could install it in any python environment with `pip install jupyter[all]`.

I do not know how to change the default jupyter environment, but you could start Jupiter notebook from the terminal (using `jupyter notebook` command) and then copy the link and use it as an exiting server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a problem with no run option showing in notebook inside VSCODE. I followed below steps:

-installed python (i got 3.9)
-installed Jupyter Notebook from pip

```
pip install notebook
```

-open VSCODE, install python extension (it comes with jupyter and pylance)

-in VSCODE, ctrl+shift+p > `python:select interpreter` (I was having problem here with error 'No interpreter found'. I solved it by ctrl+shift+p >`preferences : Open Settings (JSON)` and putting "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\Python39\python.exe")

-then installing ipykernel

```
pip install ipykernel --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org
```

-then I had to create .ipynb file manually in VSCODE by creating an new file and saving it in format .ipynb

Voila!! jupyter notebook is running.